# Gantt chart - columns and rows are not aligned

Tags: pgfgantt, charts, gantt

My problem is that I can't seem to align the columns and rows in the Gantt chart.
Namely, the first column should have a background color as in the example (Violet) and the second column (Duration) with a gray background, and the letters in both columns should be white.
Vellica's font in the first column should be the same - which is not the case in my example.

If someone has an idea and an example of how to solve the problem, it would be very useful.

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
 top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=10mm,right=10mm,
 footskip=7mm,marginparwidth=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\definecolor{Violet}{RGB}{164,84,138}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\NewDocumentCommand\textganttbarC{O{} O{} mmmm}{%
\ganttgroup[#1,group/.append style={alias=tmp,draw=red!10,line width=3pt}]{#3}{#5} 
{#6}
\node [Violet,font=\bfseries\footnotesize,at={(tmp)},#2]  {#4};
}

\NewDocumentCommand\textganttbarA{O{} O{} mmmm}{%
 \ganttgroup[#1,group/.append style={alias=tmp},
 group incomplete/.append style={draw=black!50,line width=3pt, fill=black!50}]{#3} 
 {#5}{#6}
 \node [white,fill=black!50,font=\footnotesize,at={(tmp)},#2]  {#4};
 }

 \NewDocumentCommand\textganttbarB{O{} O{} mmmm}{%
 \ganttgroup[#1,group/.append style={alias=tmp},
  group incomplete/.append style={draw=black!50,line width=3pt, fill=black!50}]{#3} 
  {#5}{#6}
   \node [white,fill=black!50,font=\footnotesize,at={(tmp)},#2]  {#4};
   } 

  \begin{document}
 \begin{landscape}
 \begin{ganttchart}[%
 title label font=\tiny,
 group label font={\bfseries\small},
 bar label font={\itshape\small},
 y unit title=4mm,
 y unit chart=5mm,
 expand chart=1.3\textwidth,
 title height=1.2,
 title/.style={draw,fill=black!10},
 bar top shift=0.2, bar height=0.9,
 group right shift=0,
 group left shift=0,
 group top shift=0,
 group height=.8,
 group peaks width={0},
 ]{1}{20}
 \gantttitle[title label node/.append style= 
 {anchor=east,align=center,fill=Violet,text=white,
 text width=40mm}]{Tasks}{1}    
 \gantttitle[title/.style={anchor=east,align=center,draw=black!50,fill=black!50}] 
 {Duration}{1}
 \gantttitle[inline,title/.style={draw=black!50,fill=black!50}]{2022}{6}
 \gantttitle[inline,title/.style={draw=black!50,fill=black!50}]{2023}{6}
 \gantttitle[inline,title/.style={draw=black!50,fill=black!50}]{2024}{6} 
 \\

\gantttitle[title label node/.append style= 
{anchor=east,align=left,fill=Violet,text=white,
text width=40mm}]{PhD Research}{1}
\gantttitle[title/.style={anchor=east,draw=black!50,fill=black!50},
 title label node/.append style= 
{anchor=east,align=center,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries}]{36}{1}
 \gantttitle{Jan-Feb}{1}       
 \gantttitle{Mar-Apr}{1}
 \gantttitle{May-Jun}{1}
 \gantttitle{Jul-Aug}{1}
 \gantttitle{Sep-Oct}{1}
 \gantttitle{Nov-Dec}{1}
 \gantttitle{Jan-Feb}{1}          
 \gantttitle{Mar-Apr}{1}
 \gantttitle{May-Jun}{1}
 \gantttitle{Jul-Aug}{1}
 \gantttitle{Sep-Oct}{1}
 \gantttitle{Nov-Dec}{1}
 \gantttitle{Jan-Feb}{1}            
 \gantttitle{Mar-Apr}{1}
 \gantttitle{May-Jun}{1}
 \gantttitle{Jul-Aug}{1}
 \gantttitle{Sep-Oct}{1}
 \gantttitle{Nov-Dec}{1}
 \\ 
 %
 \textganttbarA[progress=0]{Literature Review}{12}{1}{1}
 \textganttbarC[progress=0]{}{100\%}{2}{7} 
 \\
 \textganttbarB[progress=0]{~~\em Blockchain}{9}{1}{1} 
 \textganttbarC[progress=0]{}{100\%}{2}{4} \\

 \textganttbarB[progress=0]{~~\em Cryptography}{9}{1}{1} 
 \textganttbarC[progress=0]{}{100\%}{2}{4} \\

 \textganttbarB[progress=0]{~~\em Initial review}{1}{1}{1} 
 \textganttbarC[progress=0]{}{100\%}{3}{3} \\

 \textganttbarB[progress=0]{~~\em Internet of Things}{6}{1}{1}
 \textganttbarC[progress=0]{}{100\%}{3}{4} 
 \end{ganttchart}
 \end{landscape}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me the code is hard to follow, partly from the many options and duplicates of style commands. Was there a time, when it (almost) looked right at all? My overall intuition messages me "perhaps he's doing too much, not in the way this package was intended to work?"

Comment: @MS-SPO I agree with your comment. Maybe you can suggest some better code and example to get a solution that matches the attached picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get you started with `pgfgantt` and `Tikz` alone, reusing [Jaspers answer wrt referencing objects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703370/245790) in this package.

Basic structure:

- `tikzset` for styles of texts and node appearances
- introducing an invisible ganttbar `\newganttchartelement{invis}`
- putting titles, similar as you did
- placing `\ganttbar`s and `\ganttinvis`s
- placing nodes to the left in a relative manner, replacing the standard task-labels

About the invisible bar, it's just a trick to both:

- shift the real bar to the right
- AND having a coordinate to reference, when placing the task-nodes

For demonstration I set the invisible style to `invis/.style={draw=red!20}`, so you can see its effect. Replace by `invis/.style={draw=none}` later, which also removes an artifact at your durations.

Let's see, how it works.

First, put an invisible and a regular bar. Give a name to the invisible bar, here `B`.

```
     \ganttinvis[name=B]{}{1}{1} \ganttbar[progress=15]{}{2}{4}\\
```

Second, place a node with the duration style, anchored to said invisible bar:

```
     \node[dur] (B2)    at (B.west)  {9};
```

Finally, anchor a main- or subtask node providing the task name:

```
     \node[sub]         at (B2.west) {Blockchain};
```

Certainly, this series of commands can further be refactored into a single command. Also, "some" fine tuning is left wrt separations. alignements etc.

You can use the same concepts to add complex entries to the left of years, months etc. For coloring the gantttitles, just define and use a color via tikzset.

From a development point of view, it's useful to run through these phases, where you may want to save many versions:

- get the basic structure right with the default settings (*done*)
- introduce some colors, adjust some dimensions etc. (*in progress*)
- refactor wrt. styles, code, commands etc. (*to be done*)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
 \begin{ganttchart}[
    x unit=15mm,                            % Jan-Feb width
    y unit chart=6mm,
    toptitl/.style={title top shift=-.4},   % moving 2nd row up
 ]{1}{12}
    \tikzset{                               % styles needed
        % ~~~ color ~~~~~~~~~~~~        
        ttxt/.style={fill=red!50!blue!80,
                     text=white,
                     font=\bfseries,
                     },
        dtxt/.style={fill=black!50,text=yellow},
        % ~~~ node dimensions ~~~~~~~~
        nddim/.style={minimum height=6mm},
        % ~~~ duration node ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        dur/.style={dtxt,nddim,minimum width=8mm,anchor=east},
        % ~~~ main text ~~~~~~~~~~~
        main/.style={ttxt,nddim,minimum width=36mm,anchor=east},
        % ~~~ subitem text ~~~~~~
        sub/.style={ttxt,
                    nddim,
                    minimum width=36mm,
                    anchor=east,
                    font=\itshape,
                    },
    }    
    % ~~~ invisible ganttbar ~~~~
    \newganttchartelement{invis}{
        invis/.style={draw=red!20}  % set to: draw=none
    }
    % ~~~ years ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \gantttitle{2022}{6}
    \gantttitle{2023}{6}\\
    % ~~~ months ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \i in {1,2}                  % being lazy to copy
        \gantttitle[toptitl]{Jan-Feb}{1}
        \gantttitle[toptitl]{Mar-Apr}{1}
        \gantttitle[toptitl]{May-Jun}{1}
        \gantttitle[toptitl]{Jul-Aug}{1}
        \gantttitle[toptitl]{Sep-Oct}{1}
        \gantttitle[toptitl]{Nov-Dez}{1}; % ending the foreach path
        \\
     % ~~~ some tasks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     \ganttbar[progress=100,name=A] {}{1}{2}\\
     \ganttinvis[name=B]{}{1}{1} \ganttbar[progress=15]{}{2}{4}\\
     \ganttinvis[name=C]{}{1}{2} \ganttbar[progress=5]{}{3}{7}\\
 
     % ~~~ labels for the tasks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     \node[dur] (A2)    at (A.west)  {12};
     \node[main](A3)    at (A2.west) {Literature review};

     \node[dur] (B2)    at (B.west)  {9};
     \node[sub]         at (B2.west) {Blockchain};

     \node[dur] (C2)    at (C.west)  {5};
     \node[sub]         at (C2.west) {Cryptography};

 \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

### P.S.

Extending the concept to the title lines is a bit different, as `\gantttitle` doesn't accept a `name=` option. So, as a demonstrator, I changed these lines, and added new ones at the end:

To anchor the first title row put an invisible bar first, which DOES accept `name=`:

```
    % ~~~ years ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
    \ganttinvis[name=T]{}{1}{1}     \gantttitle{2022}{6}        % <<<
...
```

And the same inside the loop, creating 2 labels `M1` and `M2` in this case, where we need only `M1`:

```
    % ~~~ months ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \i in {1,2}
        \ganttinvis[name=M\i]{}{1}{1}   \gantttitle[toptitl]{Jan-Feb}{1}    % <<<
...
```

And finally repeat the node-placements, as indicated before: *it overwrites the former M2, but that doesn't matter here*

```
     % ~~~ trials on the titles ~~~                 % <<<
     \node[dur] (T2)    at (T.west)  {[d]};
     \node[dur] (M2)    at (M1.west)  {36};
```

Result: *the red lines and other artifacts disappear when you replace `draw=none` again*

[image: result2]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Fine. I didn‘t check if you can assign a name to \gantttitle. If not, try the box approach as shown in the link in the intro.

Comment: @ZeljkoHrcek, I added code in the P.S., how you could anchor the \gantttitle elements with a trick and apply the node concept there, too.

Answer (score 1):

The [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package can be used.

The second column uses an S column from the package [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).
The options are set with keys. For example, `column{1}={bg=Violet,fg=white}` sets a Violet background and a white foreground for the first column. Similarly, `cell{2-Z}{2}={fg=white}` sets a white foreground for the cells in the second column from the second row till the last row.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Violet}{RGB}{164,84,138}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  width=36cm,
  colspec={lS[table-format=2.0]cccccccccccccccccc},
  column{1}={bg=Violet,fg=white},
  column{2}={bg=black!50},
  cell{1}{1}=c,
  cell{3-Z}{1}={font=\em},
  cell{2-Z}{2}={fg=white},
  cell{1}{3-Z}={bg=black!50}
}
Tasks & {{{Duration}}} & \SetCell[c=6]{c} 2022 & & & & & & \SetCell[c=6]{c} 2023 & & & & & & \SetCell[c=6]{c} 2024\\
PhD Research & 36 & Jan-Feb & Mar-Apr & May-Jun & Jul-Aug & Sep-Oct & Nov-Dec & Jan-Feb & Mar-Apr & May-Jun & Jul-Aug & Sep-Oct & Nov-Dec & Jan-Feb & Mar-Apr & May-Jun & Jul-Aug & Sep-Oct & Nov-Dec\\
Literature Review & 12 & \SetCell[c=6]{c,bg=black!10,fg=Violet} \qty{100}{\percent}\\
Blockchain & 9 & \SetCell[c=5]{c,bg=black!10,fg=Violet} \qty{100}{\percent}\\
Cryptography & 9 & \SetCell[c=5]{c,bg=black!10,fg=Violet} \qty{100}{\percent}\\
Initial review & 1 & & \SetCell[c=1]{c,bg=black!10,fg=Violet} \qty{100}{\percent}\\
Internet of Things & 6 & & \SetCell[c=3]{c,bg=black!10,fg=Violet} \qty{100}{\percent}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: He you imagine to fit 36cm wide table on a4 paper?

Comment: Sorry for typing error, I mean **how** you imagine to fit 36 cm wide table ...

Comment: I realized that 36 cm would not fit on a4 paper but I decided to keep this part of the layout as provided in the question. Of course, for example "Jan-Feb" and so on can be split over 2 lines (as in your answer), or placed vertically (instead of horizontally), or replaced by the numbers of the months (to have less characters).

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram seems to be simpler to write by use of some table than use of the `pgfgantt` package. For example by use of the `tblr` of `tabularray` package table you can get the following result:

[image]

MWE, where for drawing bars is defined new command `\SCC` (you can choose different name, which is more meaningful to you), is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=10mm, vmargin=25mm, 
            footskip=7mm,
            marginparwidth=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
    \NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell[c=#1]{c, bg=gray!50, fg=violet}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=4pt,
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=violet, fg=white, font=\itshape] 
                        X[c, si={table-format=2.0}, bg=gray, fg=white]
                        *{18}{X[c, m]}},
             row{1} = {c, m, font=\textup, fg=white, guard}
            }
Tasks 
    & \SCC{1} Dura\-tion 
        &   \SCC{6} 2022
            &   &   &   &   &   &   \SCC{6} 2023
                                    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SCC{6} 2024
                                                            &   &   &   &   &   \\
Ph.D research 
    & 36 
        & Jan-Feb & Mar-Apr & May-Jun & Jul-Aug & Sep-Oct & Nov-Dec 
                                & Jan-Feb & Mar-Apr & May-Jun & Jul-Aug & Sep-Oct & Nov-Dec
                                                            & Jan-Feb  & Mar-Apr & May-Jun & Jul-Avg & Sep-Oct & Nov-Dec \\

Literature Review 
    & 12 &  \SCC{6} \qty{100}{\percent}
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    
Blockchain 
    & 9 &   \SCC{5} \qty{100}{\percent}
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
Cryptography 
    & 9 &   \SCC{5} \qty{100}{\percent}
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
Initial review 
    & 1 &   &   \SCC{6} \qty{100}{\percent}
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
Internet of Things 
    & 6 &   &   \SCC{6} \qty{100}{\percent}
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I assume, that you provide only a part of your diagram, since no bars is presented in the last year period, and you will add them in your real document. Note, in rows are according to `tabularray` syntax written all ampersands as defined in column specifications regardless if cells between them are empty. This will also make later inserting of bars more easy.