# How to obtain object coordinates in pgfganttchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

This question [Gantt chart - columns and rows are not aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703310/gantt-chart-columns-and-rows-are-not-aligned) showed some misaligned rows in a Gantt chart.

To my impression package `pgfgantt` doesn't provide the requested outcome per se. However, isolating the required changes, these could be introduced by placing more complicated Tikz-objects left of the `\ganttbar` element. **(Question)** However, I didn't find out, how to assign or retrive coordinates, e.g. from a placed `\ganttbar` element.

As an example the code below is taken from the pgfgantt manual, modified and taylored to demonstrate my question.

E.g. it's not possible to do sth. like:

```
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} (A) \\
...
    \node[green] at (A) {hi};
```

While it is possible to place a `\node` in absolute (even guessed) coordinates, see the blue text below.

I tried using the special node `bounding box` with little to no success. Instead of having the coordinate of the blue colored ganttbar, it produces something else.

May be the label node, used to write down the tasks name on the left side, can be replace, overwritten, or accessed? (Here it's left empty for the manually placed blue text.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
 \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
    \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
    {
        \ganttbar[
            bar/.append style={draw=blue,fill=blue!20}
        ]{}{8}{12}
        [local bounding box=inner box]
        \node[red]  (inner box.east) {hi world};
    }
    
    \node[green] at (0,-1) {hi};
    \node[blue,anchor=east] at (0,-3.5) {show more complex things here};
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `name` key to set a node name to a specific `\ganttbar`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
 \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
    \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttbar[
        bar/.append style={
            draw=blue,
            fill=blue!20,
        },
        name=foo
    ]{}{8}{12}
    
    \node[red, anchor=south] at (foo.north) {hi world};
    \node[green] at (foo) {hi};
    
    \node[blue, anchor=east] at (0,-3.5) {show more complex things here};    
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. I was suspecting it, but didn't find it in the manual (searching for `name` is futil, while `name=` would do ...). Very good.

Comment: @MS-SPO I checked the code of the package actually. It was not clear to me first either.